# Question about a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

Let $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$ and $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Q}(x)$ be the fields of  rational functions in $x,y$ and $x$, respectively.
Let $A$ be the subring of $\mathbb{F}$ generated by $x,y,\frac{x+1}{y},\frac{y+1}{x},\frac{x+y+1}{xy}$ and $B$ be the subring of $\mathbb{K}$ generated by $x,\frac{2}{x}$.
The map $f:A \rightarrow B$ sends $x$ to itself, $y$ to $\frac{x}{2}$ and the remaining generators from $A$ to $1$ in $B$.
I want to show that this map is a ring homomorphism.

Now, $f$ sends generators of $A$ to elements in $B$ so we have that $B \subset f(A)$. Next we want to show that $f$ preserves the addition and multiplication. Let $u,v \in A$. Then $u$ and $v$ are polynomials in the generators  of $A$ and so we write $u=p(\textbf{x})$ and $v=q(\textbf{x})$, where $\textbf{x}$ denotes the set of the generators of $A$. Then, 
\begin{equation}
f(u+v)=f(p(\textbf{x})+q(\textbf{x}))=f((p+q)(\textbf{x}))=(p+q)(f(\textbf{x}))=p(f(\textbf{x})) + q(f(\textbf{x})) = f(p(\textbf{x}))+f(q(\textbf{x})) = f(u)+f(v).
\end{equation}
Similarly, 
\begin{equation}
f(uv)=f(p(\textbf{x})q(\textbf{x}))=f((pq)(\textbf{x}))=(pq)(f(\textbf{x}))=p(f(\textbf{x}))q(f(\textbf{x})) = f(p(\textbf{x}))f(q(\textbf{x})) = f(u)f(v).
\end{equation} 
Finally, $f(1)=1$ and so $f$ is a ring homomorphism, as required. Is this correct?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific about proving the homomorphism properties (add, mult).

Comment: Is it mainly the bit where I factor through $p+q,pq$ and apply $f$ to $\textbf{x}$?

Comment: $(x+1) / y \cdot (y + 1) / x = (xy + x + y + 1) / xy$
and thus $f(1) = f((x+1) / y \cdot (y + 1) / x - (x + y + 1) / y) = 1 \cdot 1 - 1 = 0$. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: The mistake is that it's not sufficient to show that your "function" respects addition, multiplication, etc, but you also have to show that it's well-defined. That it respects addition and multiplication is in some sense true by definition, since you only define it on the generators and extend it such that it respects addition and multiplication.

Comment: @Paul K doesn't seem like you made a mistake, thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy argument. The ring $A$ is actually a subring of the ring $\mathbb Q[x^{\pm1},y^{\pm1}]$ of Laurent polynomials. To define a map $\mathbb Q[x^{\pm1},y^{\pm1}]\to\mathbb K$, one just needs to specify the images of $x$ and $y$, which must be invertible. So your map $f$ determines a ring homomorphism $\mathbb Q[x^{\pm1},y^{\pm1}]\to\mathbb K$, and hence restricts to a ring homomorphism $A\to\mathbb K$.